# Having trouble installing npm package

Tags: javascript, windows, npm, parceljs

[image]

Hello currently I'm trying to install this parcel npm( first time installing any npm) and ive watched a bunch of tutorials on how to do it but i still run into this problem, where I copy paste "npm install --save-dev parcel" into Terminal and the pop up comes up that asks which program to use to open the file with? when I try to open it via VScode i get this empty file: [image]

So the question is , am I doing something wrong or is this how you install any other package? Ty for help

Comment: That's not how you install any other package. I personnaly never used `--save-dev` option, maybe try without it. It's supposed to be easy, for example `npm i dragula` should install the dragula package

Comment: @MariusROBERT `--save-dev` is a valid option for `npm install` and it's used for installing dev-dependencies, you should definitely use it.

Comment: @Edgaras you must have misconfigured something in your system. Did you install `node.js`?